# sizeof(struct) not following padding

Tags: c, struct, structure, sizeof

Consider,

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct outside1
{
    int a;
    char b;
    char c;
    char d[3];
};

struct outside2
{
    char a,b,A[2];
    char B[2];
};

int main()
{
    printf("%zu %zu\n",sizeof(struct outside1),sizeof(struct outside2));
    return 0;
}
```

By predicting the output using the padding concepts, it would be "12 8". But the actual output is "12 6".

Using gcc 4.7.2 Debian

Can anyone explain this ?

-Newbie

Comment: It seems to follow. `char` is 1 byte. Try putting an `int` between `a` and `b` in `outside2`. The compiler should add 3 bytes (if an `int` is 4 bytes on your platform)

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd explain (by updating your question) *why* you expect `sizeof(struct outside2` to be 8 rather than 6.

Answer (score 3):

`char` and `int` have an alignment requirement of their own size on virtually any implementation.

`sizeof(char)` is 1 per standard, common sizes for `int` are 1, 2 and 4.

That leads to common sizes for `outside1` of 6, 8, 12.
And for `outside2`of 6.

BTW: The compiler is allowed to insert any amount of padding after every structure member, though it normally uses the minimum neccessary to account for alignment restriction, in order to easily follow the "common initial subsequence"-rule.

Also, since C99 or thereabouts alignments are restricted to powers of 2, and the object size must be evenly divisable by it.

Comment: Thank you @Deduplicator. That was too technical, can you put your answer in a simpler way ?

Answer (score 1):

```
struct outside2
{
    char a,b,A[2];
    char B[2];
};
```

You expect this structure to have a size of 8 bytes; in fact, its size is 6 bytes (on your implementation).

There's no need for any additional padding. An array of any type has the same alignment requirement as the element type, which means that `A` and `B` only require byte alignment.

There are a total of 6 `char` members or submembers in the structure. Since no padding is required, the total size is 6 bytes.

A compiler *could* add, say, another 2 bytes of padding at the end. It might do so if, for example, it requires all structures, or all structures above some size, to have at least 4-byte alignment. But the compiler you're using doesn't happen to do so.

The specific alignment and padding requirements can of course vary from one system to another; they're enforced by each compiler, and probably defined by the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for the platform.

Comment: Is there any platform having such a requirement for structures, independent of their actual members? Perhahp the old PDP-#?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I don't know. On SPARC, which has much stricter alignment requirements than x86, `sizeof(struct outside2) == 6`.